# Angularjs: Use ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj" to show data from json

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating one notification app which will send notification through email and SMS. Which will be set to true at starting (cant change json data)

I have created toggle button which will change status of each email and sms to true and false. when changing status to true and false, need to send json data again in below format:

```
PUT : http://example.url
{
    "category": "Fruit",
    "method": "EMAIL",
    "enabled": true
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="notification-inner-wrap" ng-repeat="settings in pgxNotification.preferences | orderBy:'order'" >
    <p class="notification-heading">{{settings.code}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in pgxNotification.preferences">
        <div class="notification-methods">
            <span>{{settings.methods[0]}}</span>
            <div class="notification-on-off-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="status = !status"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="status = !status"></i>
            </div>
            <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
        </div>
        <div class="notification-methods">
            <span>{{settings.methods[1]}}</span>
            <div class="notification-on-off-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="status = !status"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"  ng-if="status == false" ng-click="status = !status"></i>
            </div>
            <pre>{{ status }}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.status = true;
        $scope.changeStatus = function(status){
            $scope.status = !$scope.status;
            //var method = $scope.pgxNotification.methods[index];

        }


  var response = {
        "status" : true,
        "exception" : null,
        "data": {
            "methods": ["SMS","EMAIL","PUSH"],
            "preferences": [
                {
                    "code": "Fruit",
                    "name": "Fruit content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "Vegetable",
                    "name": "Vegetable content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "Car",
                    "name": "Car content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                },
                {
                    "code": "bike",
                    "name": "bike content",
                    "methods": ["SMS", "EMAIL"]
                }
            ]
        }
        };
  $scope.pgxNotification = response.data;

});
```

Here is the plunkr:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/pIBjao0ujuAzyJGZSPfU?p=preview

Right now the switch button is not working, and need to figure out on-switch how to send json response in above format.

somewhere I read that need to use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in pgxNotification.preferences"` to set key value and then send json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `status` variable at controller scope level. Hence whatever last update occur on `status` from any control will be final view value. Hence you are not getting expected output.

[Here is the updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bJPWflrQZljiQYScxL44?p=preview)

Comment: I see that now only, one toggle button status is changing to on and off But not able to catch the value true or false to send json response, In the above put method.

Comment: Okay I am able to change the value now, But can you explain me how to send json response by using put method. I am new to angular so...

which ever button toggle i change I need to send json response.

Comment: There is a problem with your technique, I dont want to initialize value to true, without it can we do it?